# Adding an overlay via background (rgba) on body:after when sidebar is clicked and run animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

So I'm trying to transition a css3 overlay via background(rgba) on the body of my site when the sidebar is clicked. I've got it working (see fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/tmbzdhwh/ - ) but for some reason I can't get the background to animate in over 1 second. Currently it's jolting in an out. I'm sure it's really simple I just can't see it.

```
<div class="sidebar">
<div class="sidebar-trigger">
    <div class="sidebar-arrow"></div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-content">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem.
</div>
```

test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic idea is that you need to animate linear values. You can't animate from nothing to a full page block with position fixed.

To make it work you need to make sure the `:after` exists from the beginning (but just not visible). The gist of it is below:

```
/* Animations */
body:after {
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

body.side-active:after {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

And a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/vh3pmrzu/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that. New I missed something.

Comment: Actually I spoke to soon. I've added a link in and now I can't click on the link even when the sidebar has been deactivated. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @FrazerFindlater Yes. It's because the mask, even transparent in the beginning is overlaying the content. Give it a `z-index: -1`. When it appears, you can either do nothing and the content will be active or change to `z-index: 1` to disable the content.

Comment: Thanks @AlinPurcaru . Lifesaver!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an :after element set for when the sidebar is not in, so it either has one or not, and it pops up/disappears (which means it doesn't get animated). Also, you're trying to transition the body, not your :after element.

So you need to change your body selector to this:

```
body:after {
    content: "";
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Check this fiddle for a working sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/tmbzdhwh/2/

Note I also removed the `content: '';` from the `body.side-active:after` as it would be just repeating itself after the above change.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the background color you're seeing jolt in isn't actually the body changing background color, that's the `::after` pseudo element appearing:

```
body.side-active:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

If you want to see the transition occur, delete that chunk of CSS, and change the next one from this:

```
body.side-active {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

to this:

```
body.side-active {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

If you need to use that `::after` element as an overlay, you'll need to create the transition effects on that instead

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the background color you set in css:

```
body.side-active {
    /*background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);*/
}

body.side-active:after {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    /*background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);*/
}
```

And now set the background color using JQuery animate:

```
$(function(){
var counter = 0;
// Toogle class on sidebar
    $( ".sidebar-trigger" ).click(function() {
    if(counter==0) {
        $('body, .sidebar').css({"backgroundColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"});
    counter=1;
    }
    else {
        $('body, .sidebar').css({"backgroundColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0)"});
    counter=0;
    }
    $('body, .sidebar').toggleClass( "side-active" );
    });
});
```